# Hello, I am trying to figure out how I can stop my sql script from adding the same value twice into the database

Tags: mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL...I have been trying to figure out how I can stop my SQL script from adding the same value twice into the database. Someone kindly help...
This is my code

```
$dan = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','grape','usersInfo');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "having problems connecting to the MysQL server.".mysqli_connect_error().'<br>';
}else{
    echo "Success establishing connection to the mySQl Database.<br><br>";
}
$pic = mysqli_query($dan, "INSERT INTO   Records(UserName,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Password)  VALUES('$user','$fName','$lName','$gender','$fPass')");
mysqli_query($dan,"DELETE FROM Records WHERE FirstName=''");
if($pic){
    echo "New user added successfully...<br><br>";
}else{
    echo "error encountered, please try again later...".mysqli_error($dan).'<br><br>';
}
mysqli_close($dan);*
```

Comment: An unique index for the column `UserName` would fix this problem. I can't imagine that you want two users with the same user name, even if both are named "John Smith"

Comment: Did you debug your code step by step?

Comment: @ Vmai, I am feeding the values into the database through <input> forms...The problem is that whenever I reload the page, the SQL query adds the latest value that I had fed into the input fields. This is annoying because I would prefer if values are inserted into database only when I fill the input fields

Comment: Use the `POST` method for your form.

Comment: I always use the post method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know the code off the top of my head, but I think you will have to run a query on the entry you are about to insert, then count the number of results. If the count is zero you insert the entry, else you don't.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Its a shame some idiot down voted.

Answer (score -1):

You can do following 
1) Before adding delete the record if present , then add 
2) while adding only add if not present .